# static page created by MS Word does not work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ms-word

I made a static page with MS Word and the page works fine in IE, but Firefox. it seems Firefox displayed it as a picture, i mean the whole page is a picture.

So my question is , is it possible to make it work in Firefox without rewriting the page?

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to tell without any specifics (a URL would be useful), but in general, MS Word generates awful code that may be heavily Microsoft-oriented. It’s less awful if you have used the option of saving as “filtered” when you save the document as a web page.

Comment: thank you for your answer,the url is here http://www.pink-geranium.de   . actually i was helping a friend. i have no idea how to covert it to standard html code. never seen that weired code before. as you said , it might be Microsoft-oriented.

Comment: Technically the page *is* just an image but with intentionally IE-specific code that consists of sort-of HTML code, hidden from browsers other than IE. So it’s hopeless to try to make work on other browsers. Instead, it might help to find the original Word version and save it as a web page in a different manner (as “filtered”) if possible.